# Magento contact form redirect

Tags: php, javascript, forms, magento

I'm working on a new site build and the site has two contact forms which run off the same controller. At the moment the form on the contact page loads a small message saying 'thanks for your inquiry' etc.. The form on the 'gallery' page, once it's submitted sends the user to the contact page and displays the same message.

However what I want is to keep the user on the page they are currently on and then display the message. Exactly what's currently happening on the contact page.

If I change this piece of code:

```
$this->_redirect('*/*/');
```

in /code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php I can get it to re-direct to the homepage etc but I just want it to display the message on the page i'm on.

Here is the code to my form:

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl(); ?>contacts/index/post/" id="contactForm" method="post">
<input type='hidden' name='formtype' value='Contact Us Page'/>
        <div class="fieldset">
               <ul class="form-list">
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
<div class="input-box">
<input onfocus="if(this.value == 'Name'){this.value = '';}"  name="name" id="name" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?>"  class="input-text required-entry" type="text" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='Name';}" value="Name"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                     <li>
<div class="input-box">
<input name="company" id="company" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Company'){this.value = '';}" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Company') ?>" value="Company" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='Company';}" class="input-text" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </li>
                    <div class="field">
                      <div class="input-box">
<input name="email" id="email" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Email'){this.value = '';}" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?>" value="Email" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='Email';}" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" type="text" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="wide">
                    <!--<label for="comment" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?></label>-->
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enquiry details'){this.value = '';}" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?>" class="required-entry input-text" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='Enquiry details';}" cols="5" value="Enquiry details" rows="3">Enquiry details</textarea>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons-set">
<input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" style="display:none !important;" />
            <button class="submit" type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
</div>
</form>




<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var contactForm = new VarienForm('contactForm', true);
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the referer URL

in /code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php

```
 if(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer(true)){
    $this->_redirectUrl(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer(true)); 
 }
 else{
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
 }
```

[Magento useful functions cheatsheet](http://www.catgento.com/magento-useful-functions-cheatsheet/)

Also you should avoid making changes to core, Take a look @ [Magento: Overriding Core Files (Blocks, Models, Resources, Controllers)](http://prattski.com/2010/06/24/magento-overriding-core-files-blocks-models-resources-controllers/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i've tried adding the above code. I now just get pointed to /contacts/index/post/ when i submit the form which gives me a blank page.

Comment: What does `print_r(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer(true)); die();` before the above code display?

Comment: I can't seem to print it out however if i add the code above that you've edited I just get the same url after i've submitted the form which is: www.website.com/contacts/index/post/

Comment: It's almost working, as i'm getting the 404 template rendering displaying the code that get displayed when the form has been submitted. The URL it's giving me now is 'http://website.co.uk/http:/index/website.co.uk/our-story/gallery/'

Comment: Take a look at my update... see http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-redirect-functions/

Comment: YES! Thank you so much! Really appreciate you taking the time to help me.